# nginx passenger server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am running rails applications with nginx+passenger

after nginx started serve, I can access it

but after sometime,may be one hour or half a day, it tells me the following message

```
Internal server error   
An error occurred while starting the web application. It sent an unknown response type "".
```

then i need to reboot the server to let nginx serve normally

My server is running on AliYun and it's memory size is only 512M, is it too small too run passenger?

or what's wrong with the configureation?

Comment: since i my rails application is running well after i reboot, i think the configuration is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's only a workaround and you should find what is the actual problem (by monitoring memory usage, processor usage, open file handles etc) but until then you can use [passenger_max_requests](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxRequests) directive